# Target every other children of each parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been struggling with this for a while, and it's time for some help.
I have this:

```html
<div class="news-images">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to target every other (a 2n+1, odd/even kind of thing) instance of the "effect" class. Is this possible with pure CSS or do i need some JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: elaborate your question???

Comment: What do you need elaborated on?

I have the mentioned piece of code where i need to select every other instance of the last child class called "effect". I'm wondering if this is possible.

Comment: `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors are what you are looking for i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You Want this? if not, Please explain briefly.

```css
.col-md-12:nth-child(odd) .effect{
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.col-md-12:nth-child(even) .effect{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-images">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect">hello world!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect">hello world!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect">hello world!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="effect">hello world!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Funny how i couldn't get it to work by myself..
Thank you very much.

Comment: It happens sometime to me too ;) . by the way Most welcome :)